# Как разместить картинку с тенью?

Tags: html, css

Есть [шаблон](https://www.figma.com/proto/dENwbjVb5X4vBUnRzauJyu/Shade-Digital-Service-Landing-Page-(Community)?node-id=1%3A2&scaling=min-zoom&page-id=0%3A1)

Есть данная картинка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я скачал ее и вставил в теге `<img>`, но она сама по себе по высоте больше(присутствует свободное пространство, height не решит проблему):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: обрезать в редакторе каком-нибудь)

Comment: Можно выгрузить 2 картинки отдельнои наложить друг на друга, так как вы хотите одной картинкой не получиться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если не убираются отступы снизу:
   IMG – строчный элемент, и поэтому к нему применяется свойство `vertical-align`. В браузерах это свойство задается по умолчанию (в большинстве baseline, если не ошибаюсь).

Достаточно к изображению применить `vertical-align:bottom` и отступа внизу не будет. В других случаях будет неоднозначность, и браузеры будут вести себя на свое усмотрение.

2. Так как занимаемое место это прямоугольник по габаритным размерам, куда входит тень, и если она вам не нужна, то можно её удалить в растровом редакторе, сделать изображение прозрачным фоном  *.png
3. Скачайте другую картинку без наклона, обрежьте пустые поля в редакторе, сохраните картинку в необходимом вам размере, заодно и вес изображения сильно уменьшится.

Comment: Саш, ты волшебник или ясновидящий? Привет, я даже вопрос не понял, пока твой ответ не прочитал....))) Сижу думаю, а тень тут при чем?

Comment: @Air ну немного телепатии приходится применять , просто ставлю себя на место спрашивающего :)))

Comment: Nick Roddy,  Вопрос надо задавать так, чтобы не возникало вопрос у других... Сегодня повезло, ответили, в следующий раз вопрос закроют....

Comment: Благодарю, друг мой...